# Find patterns in a string and replace it with simple form

Tags: python, string, parsing, pattern-matching

I have a string

`str1 = (((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15:0):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10:0):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10:0,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14:0):12:0):7):0`

and in the string, there are specific patterns ":number:number" `( ex) :15:0, :10:0 )`

I want to make them like this

```
:15:0 -> :15

:10:0 -> :10
.
.
.
```

so the final output will be

`str1 = (((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14):12):7):0`

It seemed quite simple at first, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` we can try:

```
str1 = "(((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15:0):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10:0):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10:0,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14:0):12:0):7):0"
output = re.sub(r':(\d+):\d+', r':\1', str1)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> (((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14):12):7):0

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [**`re.sub()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace).

```
import re

s = '(((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15:0):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10:0):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10:0,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14:0):12:0):7):0'
new_s = re.sub(r':((\d+):0)',r':\2', s)
print(new_s)
```

```
(((un5:0,(un7:0,un8:0):15):9,(un4:0,un10:0):10):5,((un6:0,un1:0):10,(un3:0,un9:0,un2:0):14):12):7):0
```